How to Manually Specify Different Locations to Read the OkHttp Library?
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import okhttp3.JavaNetCookieJar;
In one part of my project (in SDK), the OkHttp version is 3.x.x, and in another part, the version is 4.x.x. For some reason, Android Studio prioritizes the files from version 3.x.x. If those files are not present, it then defaults to version 4.x.x.
I want the import to work only from Gradle.
How can I manually specify where to get the library from?
